# Android alertdialog Box - Exiting from App

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to get my app to use the alertdialog box to either play another game (by clicking 'yes' or exiting the app (by clicking 'no').

I got it to reset the app fine but when trying to add the exit function ('no'), the .setTitle method is suddenly saying 'Cannot resolve method 'setTitle(java.lang.String)'

It was fine before I added the '.setNegativeButton'.

Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

Thanks

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
  AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Task1Activity.this);
  alert.setMessage("You have guessed incorrectly three times. " +
  "The answer was " + ranNum + ". " + "Would you like to play again?")
  .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
  //dialog.dismiss();
  Intent i = new Intent(Task1Activity.this, Task1Activity.class);
  startActivity(i);

}
});

  alert
  .setCancelable(false)
  .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

};
}
.setTitle("Unlucky!")
.create());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a missing ) bracket just before .setTitle(...) I think.

Comment: Thank you.  That was it!